# Detect if a UICollectionViewCell is being displayed

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have set a UICollectionView to 'Paging Enabled'. I want to be informed when a UICollectionViewCell becomes active.

It seems like the `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` of the UICollectionViewController cannot achieve this effect: It only fires when a user explicitly select a cell, not when the cell is swiped to the front.

Each cell has a view controller associated with it. I probably can use `viewDidLoad` to as a proxy of this event. But it does not sound like a clean solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` to detect that something changed and `visibleCells` to know what now on screen

Comment: This would not appear to help in detecting the *first* cell being displayed. didEndDisplayingCell will not be called.